# Compare two compound columns in two tables

Tags: kdb

I have two tables(see below) with sym and lp. I want to pull out every row from tab1 that doesn't have the complete set of symbols corresponding to the
same sym from tab2.

```
tab1:([]sym:`EUR`AUD`GBP;lp:(`aa`bb`cc;`dd`ee;`ff`gg`aa`ee))
tab2:([]sym:`EUR`AUD`GBP;lp:(`aa`bb`ff`cc;`ee`dd;`gg`ff`ee`aa`rr`xx))
```

i.e. my result should be:

```
tab3:([]sym:`EUR`GBP;lp:(`ff;`rr`xx))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might fit what you're looking for:

```
q)b: where 0 <> count each a: (exec lp from tab2) except' (exec lp from tab1)
q)update lp: a b from tab1 b
sym lp
----------
EUR ,`ff
GBP `rr`xx
```

One assumption that I've made is that you always have the syms in the same order in both tables, is this always true?

Comment: I can ensure they are. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I will be able to make this assumption - tab2 will be the total set of syms, there is a high chance tab1 won't include every sym - I have left-joined the two tables and tried to extend your use case to this one table (pulling out both columns) but am getting a length error

Comment: Well, you could try either
`select lp by sym from {except[x 1; x 0]} ungroup each 1 !' (tab1; tab2)`
or, if you don't mind having nulls in the table,
`update lp: {(1 ! tab2)[x][\`lp] except y}'[sym; lp] from tab1`.
If neither of these work, would you be able to provide some more descriptive tables? Thanks!

Comment: The second way worked perfectly! thanks again Matthew

Answer (score 0):

An `except` on keyed tables might work here also:

```
q)(1!tab2)except''1!tab1
sym| lp
---| ----------
EUR| ,`ff
AUD| `symbol$()
GBP| `rr`xx
```

Performance wouldn't be good though.